# How to disable Alt + Shift + Tab using c#?

Tags: c#

How to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↹Tab</kbd> using c# ? I have disabled the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↹Tab</kbd> using a function which gets only two parameters. But to disable three key strokes ??

I anyone need my code to disable the two key strokes combination, i cam post it. But it is quite big.

To disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↹Tab</kbd> I do this,

```
RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.Tab, USE_ALT);
```

How to pass three parameters [Alt, Shift, Tab] ??

```
   public sealed class KeyboardHook : IDisposable
{
    // Registers a hot key with Windows.
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
    // Unregisters the hot key with Windows.
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the window that is used internally to get the messages.
    /// </summary>
    private class Window : NativeWindow, IDisposable
    {
        private static int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

        public Window()
        {
            // create the handle for the window.
            try
            {
                this.CreateHandle(new CreateParams());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.writeToLogFile(System.Environment.NewLine + "Target  :  " + ex.TargetSite.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + "Message :  " + ex.Message.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + "Stack   :  " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Overridden to get the notifications.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="m"></param>
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            try
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);

                // check if we got a hot key pressed.
                if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
                {
                    // get the keys.
                    Keys key = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
                    ModifierKeys modifier = (ModifierKeys)((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);

                    // invoke the event to notify the parent.
                    if (KeyPressed != null)
                        KeyPressed(this, new KeyPressedEventArgs(modifier, key));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.writeToLogFile(System.Environment.NewLine + "Target  :  " + ex.TargetSite.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + "Message :  " + ex.Message.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + "Stack   :  " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> KeyPressed;

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.DestroyHandle();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    private Window _window = new Window();
    private int _currentId;

    public KeyboardHook()
    {
        try
        {
            // register the event of the inner native window.
            _window.KeyPressed += delegate(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs args)
            {
                if (KeyPressed != null)
                    KeyPressed(this, args);
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.writeToLogFile(System.Environment.NewLine + "Target  :  " + ex.TargetSite.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + "Message :  " + ex.Message.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + "Stack   :  " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a hot key in the system.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modifier">The modifiers that are associated with the hot key.</param>
    /// <param name="key">The key itself that is associated with the hot key.</param>
    public void RegisterHotKey(ModifierKeys modifier, Keys key)
    {
        try
        {
            // increment the counter.
            _currentId = _currentId + 1;

            // register the hot key.
            if (!RegisterHotKey(_window.Handle, _currentId, (uint)modifier, (uint)key))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn’t register the hot key.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.writeToLogFile(System.Environment.NewLine + "Target  :  " + ex.TargetSite.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + "Message :  " + ex.Message.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + "Stack   :  " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        }
    } 

    /// <summary>
    /// A hot key has been pressed.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> KeyPressed;

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // unregister all the registered hot keys.
        for (int i = _currentId; i > 0; i--)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(_window.Handle, i);
        }

        // dispose the inner native window.
        _window.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Event Args for the event that is fired after the hot key has been pressed.
/// </summary>
public class KeyPressedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private ModifierKeys _modifier;
    private Keys _key;

    internal KeyPressedEventArgs(ModifierKeys modifier, Keys key)
    {
        _modifier = modifier;
        _key = key;
    }

    public ModifierKeys Modifier
    {
            get { return _modifier; }
        }

        public Keys Key
        {
            get { return _key; }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The enumeration of possible modifiers.
    /// </summary>
    [Flags]
    public enum ModifierKeys : uint
    {
        Alt = 1,
        Control = 2,
        Shift = 4,
        Win = 8
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to? If it's what I suspect, did you take care of Win+Tab, Win+Shift+Tab, Alt+Esc, Alt+Shift+Esc, Ctrl+Esc, Ctrl+Pause, Win+D, Win+M, ... too? (For the record: I'm suspecting that you want a kiosk application that will prevent the user from doing anything to leave the application.) In that case I'd suggest you simply don't give the user a keyboard.

Comment: Did like this : 
var TabShift = Keys.Tab | Keys.Shift;
RegisterGlobalHotKey(TabShift, USE_ALT);

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3581059/56778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention you use a function which takes 2 parameters but you didn't mention which function it was. In any case, `Keys.Shift` and `Keys.Alt` are modifier keys so whatever you are passing "Alt" into you would probably need to bitwise OR that with "Shift".

In WPF this would be something like:

```
var altShift = Keys.Alt | Keys.Shift;
```

Comment: Find the code above, which works fine for two parameters. I want to use three parameters now.

Comment: Okay, so it's like I said... Where you're currently passing ModifierKeys.Alt, you would instead pass ModifierKeys.Alt|ModifierKeys.Shift.