# windows to run only one application, no minimize

Tags: windows, kiosk-mode

I wanted to configure a windows machine in such a way that, just after starting it runs a specific application on full screen. Now User can use this application only.

No minimize will be allowed, its like giving exam on a computer.

How to securely configure in that way ?

Comment: Are you making the software? Or do you have access to the source code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Kiosk App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581059/windows-kiosk-app)

Comment: There are multiples ways to skin this cat.  You can use Group Policy to auto login and auto start a specific application and lock down that application so it stays maximize. But there are a lot of clever ways to get around things like this.  Off the top of my head, you would need policy to disable ctrl-alt-delete allowing them access to Task Manager.  One thing I would probably do is modify the windows registry and swap out the windows explorer.exe shell with the application .exe.  If the explorer shell isn't running, that will block a lot of the clever ways you can circumvent things.

Comment: Your better bet would be to look at kiosk software, where they have specialized in providing what you need and have had a lot more time and experience architecting such things.

Answer (score -2):

step 1-: open Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings.

step 2-: You can also click Start, type “sysdm.cpl” into the search box, and press “Enter” to instantly launch this window

step 3-: Click the “Advanced” tab in the System Properties window and click the “Settings” button under Performance.

step 4-: Uncheck the “Animate windows when minimizing or maximizing” option here and click “OK”.

for the more information https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9101/make-aero-enabled-windows-run-more-smoothly-in-vista-and-windows-7/

Comment: Turning off animations doesn't stop programs from being minimized.